# Python/Pandas —replace NaN in a column with empty/blank, another column with 0. Is it possible to selectively replace Nan?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi just started learning Python or Programming itself and trying to read DataFrame from Excel and incert it in email.
There is a blank in string column where I want to replace Nan with just blank. Elsewhere I have another int-column I want to format as {:1f} but it also includes NaN sometimes because I use =IFERROR(...,""), that's when formating returns error.
How can I solve this other than fixing formula in excel as =IFERROR(...,0)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need sample input data, expected output of the dataframe, and any errors you are coming across (paste the error message in your question). Kindly read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples , which help you understand how to improve your question and increase the chances that you will get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use converters in the `pd.read_excel` function when you are reading the sheet.

```
pd.read_excel('sheet.xlsx', sheet_name='bad', 
              converters={'string_col': lambda x: '' if pd.isna(x) else x,
                          'int_col': lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else round(x,1)
              }
)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your advice.
I tried this but no changes.
I assume if you try to convert NaN data to ' ' at read option it just turns to NaN again.
I think I need styler format that makes object as it is but with na_rep otion. 
I'm grateful anyway I come to know about converter.

Comment: Very strange.
I made sure the dtype of 'string_coI' is Object and I also tried 
    converters={'string_col': lambda x: 'N' if pd.isna(x)==False else x
Then all turned to 'N'.
If I make it ==True then NaN doesn't change to 'N'.
So NaN is not detected by isna? But if you make
    ,keep_default_na=False
It sure replaces NaN in 'string...' with blank.

Anyway I come through this with
    set_na_rep('')
after done all other styling.